# Catch everything between two same words multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this huge text, and i would like to catch everything between the words "Empresa". I'm trying to, but the second regex is being ignored, and i can't figure it out why:

```
/(Empresa.*?Empresa)/
```

http://regexr.com/3cm8a

The problem is, i can catch Empresa - EVERYTHING - Empresa.. But the next, is being ignored, because is being used by the previous regex.

So, i would like to improve to catch at all, but i can't figure it out how.

Thanks!!!

Comment: "Empresa" does not occur in your example. A regular expression will by default only match things on the same line btw.

Comment: After I answer such questions, I always forget to save a link for closing such dupes... Use `/Empresa.*?(?=Empresa|$)/`. Or unroll it for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need *overlapping* matches, you need to put the *trailing* delimiter into a lookahead zero-width assertion (zero-width assertions do not consume the text, only check if something is present or not).

```
/Empresa.*?(?=Empresa|$)/g
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB2mY2/2)

Note that in order to match any characters including a newline, you need to replace `.` with `[\s\S]`.

```js
var re = /Empresa[\s\S]*?(?=Empresa|$)/g; 
var str = '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Empresa SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA Folha Fiscal P�gina: 1 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 31/01/2011 - 09:17:54 Estabelecimento: 1 - SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA S/A-HOL Referente : 01/2011 Tipo Folha : 1 Parcela : 9 -----------------------------------------------------Total Estabelecimento ----------------------------------------------------- Evt Descri��o HorMOB Func Quant Horas Base C�lculo Valor Liq --- ------------------------------ --- ---- ------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------------- ----- 001 Salario Base Ho IND 1 21,990 21,990 0,00 13,13 + Total Evento : 1 21,990 21,990 0,00 13,13 *** 017 Aviso Previo Indenizado Di IND 1 30,000 219,999 0,00 131,39 + Total Evento : 1 30,000 219,999 0,00 131,39 *** 028 Abono Indenizatorio Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.100,00 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.100,00 *** 037 Repouso Remunerado Adicionais Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 48,32 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 48,32 *** 062 F�rias Prop - Aviso Indenizado Di IND 1 2,500 18,333 0,00 10,94 + Total Evento : 1 2,500 18,333 0,00 10,94 *** 064 F�rias Prop 1/3 - Aviso Inden Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 3,64 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 3,64 *** 082 Devolucao Desc Indevido Consel Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 57.000,00 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 57.000,00 *** 099 Pro Labore Conselho Ho IND 4 880,000 880,000 0,00 801.541,63 + Total Evento : 4 880,000 880,000 0,00 801.541,63 *** 106 Hora Extra 60% Ho IND 1 194,320 194,320 0,00 185,68 + Total Evento : 1 194,320 194,320 0,00 185,68 *** 109 Hrs. Extra (80%) Ho IND 1 51,240 51,240 0,00 55,07 + Total Evento : 1 51,240 51,240 0,00 55,07 *** 230 Ferias Proporcionais Di IND 1 25,000 183,333 0,00 109,49 + Total Evento : 1 25,000 183,333 0,00 109,49 *** 232 Ferias Proporcionais 1/3 Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 36,49 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 36,49 *** 233 Ferias Venc Indenizadas Di IND 1 30,000 219,999 0,00 131,39 + Total Evento : 1 30,000 219,999 0,00 131,39 *** 234 Ferias Venc Adic Indenizadas Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 14,59 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 14,59 *** 236 Ferias Venc 1/3 Indenizadas Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 48,66 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 48,66 *** 380 13. Salario Indenizado Av IND 1 9,000 164,999 0,00 98,54 + Total Evento : 1 9,000 164,999 0,00 98,54 *** 381 13. Salario Aviso Indenizado Av IND 1 1,000 18,333 0,00 10,94 + Total Evento : 1 1,000 18,333 0,00 10,94 *** 412 Estorno FGTS Provisoes Ferias Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 340,62 27,24 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 340,62 27,24 *** 447 Desc Adto Honorario Conselho Va IND 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 98.261,00 - Total Evento : 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 98.261,00 *** 448 Desc Assistencia Medica Cons Va IND 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.481,90 - Total Evento : 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.481,90 *** 449 Desconto Diversos Conselho Va IND 4 0,000 0,000 0,00 62.234,04 - Total Evento : 4 0,000 0,000 0,00 62.234,04 *** 491 Seguro de Vida Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 34,20 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 34,20 *** 511 INSS Normal Va IND 5 0,000 0,000 801.975,22 1.658,12 - Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 801.975,22 1.658,12 *** 512 INSS sobre 13. Salario Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 109,48 8,75 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 109,48 8,75 *** 535 FGTS Normal Indenizado Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 433,59 34,69 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 433,59 34,69 *** 536 FGTS 13o Indenizado Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 109,48 8,76 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 109,48 8,76 *** -----------------------------------------------------------------------------DATASUL - Folha de Pagamento - FP4000RP - V:1.02.02.037 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Empresa SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA Folha Fiscal P�gina: 2 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 31/01/2011 - 09:17:55 Estabelecimento: 1 - SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA S/A-HOL Referente : 01/2011 Tipo Folha : 1 Parcela : 9 -----------------------------------------------------Total Estabelecimento ----------------------------------------------------- Evt Descri��o ValMOB Func Quant Horas Base C�lculo Valor Liq --- ------------------------------ --- ---- ------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------------- ----- 537 Contr.Social FGTS Normal Ind. Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 433,59 0,00 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 433,59 0,00 *** 538 Contr.Social FGTS D�cimo Ind. Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 109,48 0,00 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 109,48 0,00 *** 539 Contr.Social Multa FGTS Ind. Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 43,45 4,35 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 43,45 4,35 *** 540 FGTS Multa Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 43,45 17,38 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 43,45 17,38 *** 561 IRF (Normal) Va IND 4 0,000 0,000 798.411,29 216.791,97 - Total Evento : 4 0,000 0,000 798.411,29 216.791,97 *** 565 IRF Recolhido no Pgto 13. Sal Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 100,73 0,00 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 100,73 0,00 *** 566 IRF Recolhido no Pgto Normal Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 267,52 0,00 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 267,52 0,00 *** 802 Complemento Rescisoes a Pagar Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.954,84 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.954,84 *** Total Funcion�rios : 5 Total Vencimentos : 860.539,90 Total Descontos : 383.424,82 Total L�quido : 477.115,08 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------DATASUL - Folha de Pagamento - FP4000RP - V:1.02.02.037 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Empresa SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA Folha Fiscal P�gina: 3 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 31/01/2011 - 09:18:05 Estabelecimento: 3 - SANTHER-FAB PAPEL STA THEREZINHA S/A-EUZ Referente : 01/2011 Tipo Folha : 1 Parcela : 9 -----------------------------------------------------Total Estabelecimento ----------------------------------------------------- Evt Descri��o HorMOB Func Quant Horas Base C�lculo Valor Liq --- ------------------------------ --- ---- ------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------------- ----- 001 Salario Base Ho DIR 1 73,333 73,333 0,00 1.341,66 + IND 146 26.333,967 26.333,967 0,00 785.445,38 + Total Evento : 147 26.407,300 26.407,300 0,00 786.787,04 *** 002 Gratificacao Va IND 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 222.237,50 + Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 222.237,50 *** 004 Pro-Labore Ho IND 2 293,333 293,333 0,00 51.127,61 + Total Evento : 2 293,333 293,333 0,00 51.127,61 *** 016 Indenizacao Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 119,00 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 119,00 *** 017 Aviso Previo Indenizado Di IND 4 120,000 879,996 0,00 24.889,00 + Total Evento : 4 120,000 879,996 0,00 24.889,00 *** 023 Devolucao Desconto Indevido Va IND 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 539,75 + Total Evento : 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 539,75 *** 028 Abono Indenizatorio Va IND 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 5.500,00 + Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 5.500,00 *** 031 Hrs Repouso Remunerado Venc Ho ind 1 21,999 21,999 0,00 23,80 + Total Evento : 1 21,999 21,999 0,00 23,80 *** 037 Repouso Remunerado Adicionais Va IND 5 100,350 0,000 2.841,21 570,19 + Total Evento : 5 100,350 0,000 2.841,21 570,19 *** 048 Auxilio Filho Excepcional Va IND 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.600,00 + Total Evento : 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.600,00 *** 049 Reembolso Creche Va IND 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 642,00 + Total Evento : 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 642,00 *** 062 F�rias Prop - Aviso Indenizado Di IND 4 10,000 73,332 0,00 2.074,09 + Total Evento : 4 10,000 73,332 0,00 2.074,09 *** 063 F�rias Prop Adic - Aviso Inden Va ind 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 105,17 + Total Evento : 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 105,17 *** 064 F�rias Prop 1/3 - Aviso Inden Va IND 4 0,000 0,000 0,00 726,43 + Total Evento : 4 0,000 0,000 0,00 726,43 *** 079 Devolucao Contrib Confederativ Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 150,00 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 150,00 *** 080 Premio Produt mes anterior Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.276,87 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.276,87 *** 106 Hora Extra 60% Ho IND 5 130,547 130,547 0,00 921,75 + Total Evento : 5 130,547 130,547 0,00 921,75 *** 109 Hrs. Extra (80%) Ho IND 5 57,184 57,184 0,00 1.322,27 + Total Evento : 5 57,184 57,184 0,00 1.322,27 *** 126 Adicional Noturno 40% Ho ind 2 10,660 10,660 0,00 46,00 + Total Evento : 2 10,660 10,660 0,00 46,00 *** 129 Hora Extra Noturna Ho ind 2 0,761 0,761 0,00 26,28 + Total Evento : 2 0,761 0,761 0,00 26,28 *** 141 Horas de Sobreaviso Ho IND 1 123,000 123,000 0,00 495,12 + Total Evento : 1 123,000 123,000 0,00 495,12 *** 171 Hrs Salario Maternidade Ho IND 1 58,667 58,667 881,87 881,87 + Total Evento : 1 58,667 58,667 881,87 881,87 *** 221 Ferias Normais Di DIR 1 20,000 146,667 0,00 2.683,33 + ind 51 701,000 5.140,609 0,00 146.237,43 + Total Evento : 52 721,000 5.287,276 0,00 148.920,76 *** 222 Ferias Adicionais Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 54,66 + ind 41 0,000 0,000 0,00 20.021,47 + Total Evento : 42 0,000 0,000 0,00 20.076,13 *** 224 Ferias Abono Di DIR 1 9,000 66,000 0,00 1.207,50 + -----------------------------------------------------------------------------DATASUL - Folha de Pagamento - FP4000RP - V:1.02.02.037 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Empresa SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA Folha Fiscal P�gina: 4 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 31/01/2011 - 09:18:06 Estabelecimento: 3 - SANTHER-FAB PAPEL STA THEREZINHA S/A-EUZ Referente : 01/2011 Tipo Folha : 1 Parcela : 9 -----------------------------------------------------Total Estabelecimento ----------------------------------------------------- Evt Descri��o DiaMOB Func Quant Horas Base C�lculo Valor Liq --- ------------------------------ --- ---- ------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------------- ----- IND 43 404,000 2.962,627 0,00 74.288,86 + Total Evento : 44 413,000 3.028,627 0,00 75.496,36 *** 226 Ferias Abono Adicionais Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 24,60 + IND 37 0,000 0,000 0,00 14.502,20 + Total Evento : 38 0,000 0,000 0,00 14.526,80 *** 227 Ferias 1/3 Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 912,66 + ind 51 0,000 0,000 0,00 55.419,63 + Total Evento : 52 0,000 0,000 0,00 56.332,29 *** 229 Ferias 1/3 sobre Abono Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 410,70 + IND 43 0,000 0,000 0,00 29.597,04 + Total Evento : 44 0,000 0,000 0,00 30.007,74 *** 230 Ferias Proporcionais Di IND 9 145,000 1.063,279 0,00 40.083,34 + Total Evento : 9 145,000 1.063,279 0,00 40.083,34 *** 231 Ferias Proporcionais Adic Va ind 6 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.973,11 + Total Evento : 6 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.973,11 *** 232 Ferias Proporcionais 1/3 Va IND 9 0,000 0,000 0,00 14.018,81 + Total Evento : 9 0,000 0,000 0,00 14.018,81 *** 233 Ferias Venc Indenizadas Di IND 3 90,000 659,997 0,00 6.889,00 + Total Evento : 3 90,000 659,997 0,00 6.889,00 *** 234 Ferias Venc Adic Indenizadas Va IND 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.262,08 + Total Evento : 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.262,08 *** 236 Ferias Venc 1/3 Indenizadas Va IND 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.717,02 + Total Evento : 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.717,02 *** 237 Ferias Pagas no Mes Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 4.715,99 - ind 51 0,000 0,000 0,00 307.512,39 - Total Evento : 52 0,000 0,000 0,00 312.228,38 *** 240 Dif Ferias Abono Adicionais Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 106,40 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 106,40 *** 246 Adt Complemento Ferias Venc Va IND 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 238,63 + Total Evento : 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 238,63 *** 261 Salario Familia Va ind 2 0,000 0,000 13.609,48 0,00 + Total Evento : 2 0,000 0,000 13.609,48 0,00 *** 272 Aviso Previo Ad Indenizacao Va ind 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.269,21 + Total Evento : 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.269,21 *** 301 Aviso Previo Indeniz Funcionar Ho ind 1 1,000 1,000 0,00 3.998,99 - Total Evento : 1 1,000 1,000 0,00 3.998,99 *** 351 Premio Produtividade Va IND 67 0,000 0,000 0,00 79.211,57 + Total Evento : 67 0,000 0,000 0,00 79.211,57 *** 377 13. Salario Proporcional Av IND 4 22,000 403,331 0,00 797,00 + Total Evento : 4 22,000 403,331 0,00 797,00 *** 380 13. Salario Indenizado Av IND 4 22,000 403,332 0,00 5.190,84 + Total Evento : 4 22,000 403,332 0,00 5.190,84 *** 381 13. Salario Aviso Indenizado Av IND 3 3,000 54,999 0,00 2.054,25 + Total Evento : 3 3,000 54,999 0,00 2.054,25 *** 383 13. Salario Adic Proporcional Va IND 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 107,33 + Total Evento : 3 0,000 0,000 0,00 107,33 *** 386 13. Salario Adic Indenizado Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 19,23 + Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 19,23 *** 390 Previdencia Privada Normal Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 92,61 - IND 10 0,000 0,000 0,00 4.710,45 - Total Evento : 11 0,000 0,000 0,00 4.803,06 *** 392 Previd Privada p/IR Normal Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.720,00 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.720,00 *** -----------------------------------------------------------------------------DATASUL - Folha de Pagamento - FP4000RP - V:1.02.02.037 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Empresa SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA Folha Fiscal P�gina: 5 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 31/01/2011 - 09:18:07 Estabelecimento: 3 - SANTHER-FAB PAPEL STA THEREZINHA S/A-EUZ Referente : 01/2011 Tipo Folha : 1 Parcela : 9 -----------------------------------------------------Total Estabelecimento ----------------------------------------------------- Evt Descri��o ValMOB Func Quant Horas Base C�lculo Valor Liq --- ------------------------------ --- ---- ------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------------- ----- 399 Prev Privada Empresa Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 92,61 IND 10 0,000 0,000 0,00 4.640,45 Total Evento : 11 0,000 0,000 0,00 4.733,06 *** 404 Adiantamento Normal Desconto Va ind 110 0,000 0,000 0,00 380.194,50 - Total Evento : 110 0,000 0,000 0,00 380.194,50 *** 405 Plano Saude UNIMED Va IND 63 0,000 0,000 0,00 9.696,00 - Total Evento : 63 0,000 0,000 0,00 9.696,00 *** 407 Outras Despesas Alimenta��o Va IND 12 0,000 0,000 0,00 63,20 - Total Evento : 12 0,000 0,000 0,00 63,20 *** 412 Estorno FGTS Provisoes Ferias Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 1.642,80 131,42 IND 51 0,000 0,000 185.331,46 14.826,30 Total Evento : 52 0,000 0,000 186.974,26 14.957,72 *** 416 13. Salario Adiantamento Venc Va ind 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 18.513,00 + Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 18.513,00 *** 420 Adiant. Contrib Confed mes ant Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 150,00 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 150,00 *** 421 Adiant. Premio Prod m�s anter Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.276,87 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.276,87 *** 422 Desc Gratificacao Contratual Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 39.000,00 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 39.000,00 *** 451 Mensalidade Sindical Va ind 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 39,34 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 39,34 *** 454 Contrib Confederativa Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 40,25 - IND 75 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.818,83 - Total Evento : 76 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.859,08 *** 463 Desc Assist.Medica Mes Anter. Va ind 43 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.302,60 - Total Evento : 43 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.302,60 *** 464 Desc Assist.Med.Mes Anter.II Va ind 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 733,93 - Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 0,00 733,93 *** 467 Assist Medica (Func) Va ind 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 140,00 - Total Evento : 2 0,000 0,000 0,00 140,00 *** 468 Assist Medica (Parte Empresa) Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 279,82 ind 138 0,000 0,000 0,00 72.681,58 Total Evento : 139 0,000 0,000 0,00 72.961,40 *** 471 Assistencia Medica Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 93,28 - ind 75 0,000 0,000 0,00 12.022,75 - Total Evento : 76 0,000 0,000 0,00 12.116,03 *** 474 Assistencia Odontologica Va IND 50 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.236,48 - Total Evento : 50 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.236,48 *** 475 Materiais Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 108,16 - ind 32 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.648,18 - Total Evento : 33 0,000 0,000 0,00 2.756,34 *** 476 Restaurante Va ind 9 11,000 0,000 0,00 24,62 - Total Evento : 9 11,000 0,000 0,00 24,62 *** 478 Auxilio Refeicao mes ant Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 240,00 - Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 240,00 *** 485 Cesta Basica Empresa Va ind 8 0,000 0,000 0,00 828,00 Total Evento : 8 0,000 0,000 0,00 828,00 *** 486 Cesta Basica Funcionario Va ind 8 0,000 0,000 0,00 92,00 - Total Evento : 8 0,000 0,000 0,00 92,00 *** 488 Cartao Alimentacao Empresa Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 103,50 ind 97 0,000 0,000 0,00 10.039,50 Total Evento : 98 0,000 0,000 0,00 10.143,00 *** -----------------------------------------------------------------------------DATASUL - Folha de Pagamento - FP4000RP - V:1.02.02.037 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Empresa SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA Folha Fiscal P�gina: 6 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 31/01/2011 - 09:18:07 Estabelecimento: 3 - SANTHER-FAB PAPEL STA THEREZINHA S/A-EUZ Referente : 01/2011 Tipo Folha : 1 Parcela : 9 -----------------------------------------------------Total Estabelecimento ----------------------------------------------------- Evt Descri��o ValMOB Func Quant Horas Base C�lculo Valor Liq --- ------------------------------ --- ---- ------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------------- ----- 489 Cartao Alimentacao Funcionario Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 11,50 - ind 97 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.115,50 - Total Evento : 98 0,000 0,000 0,00 1.127,00 *** 491 Seguro de Vida Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 32,23 - IND 144 0,000 0,000 0,00 5.023,94 - Total Evento : 145 0,000 0,000 0,00 5.056,17 *** 493 Seguro de Vida (Parte Empresa) Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 21,49 ind 144 0,000 0,000 0,00 3.349,46 Total Evento : 145 0,000 0,000 0,00 3.370,95 *** 497 Aux Refeicao - Empresa Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 281,60 ind 140 0,000 0,000 0,00 41.008,00 Total Evento : 141 0,000 0,000 0,00 41.289,60 *** 498 Aux Refeicao - Funcionario Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 0,00 70,40 - ind 141 0,000 0,000 0,00 10.401,60 - Total Evento : 142 0,000 0,000 0,00 10.472,00 *** 506 Vale Transporte (MB) Va IND 4 160,000 0,000 0,00 379,36 - Total Evento : 4 160,000 0,000 0,00 379,36 *** 507 Vale Transp-Emp MB Va IND 4 160,000 0,000 0,00 215,04 Total Evento : 4 160,000 0,000 0,00 215,04 *** 511 INSS Normal Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 4.992,31 405,86 - IND 149 0,000 0,000 1.390.828,61 53.936,26 - Total Evento : 150 0,000 0,000 1.395.820,92 54.342,12 *** 512 INSS sobre 13. Salario Va IND 9 0,000 0,000 8.168,65 840,97 - Total Evento : 9 0,000 0,000 8.168,65 840,97 *** 519 Base INSS negativa Va IND 1 0,000 0,000 490,45 0,00 Total Evento : 1 0,000 0,000 490,45 0,00 *** 531 FGTS Normal Dep�sito Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 1.341,66 107,33 ind 144 0,000 0,000 1.000.008,08 80.000,50 Total Evento : 145 0,000 0,000 1.001.349,74 80.107,83 *** 532 FGTS 13o Deposito Va ind 10 0,000 0,000 22.667,33 1.813,38 Total Evento : 10 0,000 0,000 22.667,33 1.813,38 *** 535 FGTS Normal Indenizado Va IND 5 0,000 0,000 169.142,00 13.531,35 Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 169.142,00 13.531,35 *** 536 FGTS 13o Indenizado Va IND 4 0,000 0,000 4.014,32 321,14 Total Evento : 4 0,000 0,000 4.014,32 321,14 *** 537 Contr.Social FGTS Normal Ind. Va IND 5 0,000 0,000 169.142,00 0,00 Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 169.142,00 0,00 *** 538 Contr.Social FGTS D�cimo Ind. Va IND 4 0,000 0,000 4.014,32 0,00 Total Evento : 4 0,000 0,000 4.014,32 0,00 *** 539 Contr.Social Multa FGTS Ind. Va IND 5 0,000 0,000 91.690,06 9.169,01 Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 91.690,06 9.169,01 *** 540 FGTS Multa Va IND 5 0,000 0,000 91.690,06 36.676,02 Total Evento : 5 0,000 0,000 91.690,06 36.676,02 *** 542 Contr.Social FGTS Normal Dep. Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 1.341,66 0,00 ind 144 0,000 0,000 1.000.008,08 0,00 Total Evento : 145 0,000 0,000 1.001.349,74 0,00 *** 543 Contr.Social FGTS Decimo Dep. Va ind 10 0,000 0,000 22.667,33 0,00 Total Evento : 10 0,000 0,000 22.667,33 0,00 *** 551 FGTS Ferias Deposito Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 3.650,65 292,05 ind 51 0,000 0,000 221.678,53 17.734,04 Total Evento : 52 0,000 0,000 225.329,18 18.026,09 *** 561 IRF (Normal) Va DIR 1 0,000 0,000 1.073,91 0,00 - -----------------------------------------------------------------------------DATASUL - Folha de Pagamento - FP4000RP - V:1.02.02.037 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Empresa SANTHER-FAB.PAPEL STA THEREZINHA Folha Fiscal P�gina: 7 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 31/01/2011 - 09:18:08 Estabelecimento: 3 - SANTHER-FAB PAPEL STA THEREZINHA S/A-EUZ Referente : 01/2011 Tipo Folha : 1 Parcela : 9 -----------------------------------------------------Total Estabelecimento ----------------------------------------------------- Evt Descri��o ValMOB Func Quant Horas Base C�lculo Valor Liq --- ------------------------------ --- ---- ------- ------------- ------------- ------------------ ----------------- ----- IND 139 0,000 0,000 902.828,07 163.379,23 - Total Evento : 140 0,000 0,000 903.901,98 163.379,23 *** 562 IRF (Ferias) Va IND 2 0,000 0,000 4.572,85 156,98 - Total Evento : 2 0,000 0,000 4.572,85 156,98 ';
var arr = str.match(re);
if (arr) {
 document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
}
```

An alternative expression you can use is:

```
/Empresa[^E]*(?:E(?!mpresa)[^E]*)*/g
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB2mY2/1)

Also, a good note is made by @neuhaus in his answer: `/g` modifier is necessary to match multiple occurrences of text. See [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method docs:

> If the regular expression does not include the `g` flag, returns the same result as `RegExp.exec()`...
>   **If the regular expression includes the `g` flag**, the method **returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects**. Captured groups are not returned. If there were no matches, the method returns `null`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `/g` modifier for the regexp to match multiple times.

Then `.match()` will return a list you can iterate over.

Comment: However, that will not help OP match overlapping substrings.

Comment: Yours seem to be important, too. I see a lot of people still need to read more about `String#match` method.